# Plot discrete points with a density value as individual rectangles

Tags: plotting

I have a 2D array with (x, y, val) coordinates. Example,

```
data = {{1, 1, 0.5}, {1, 0, 0.5), ...}
```

One can think of the x, y indices as array indices. They are discrete.

I want to create a plot where each (x, y) pair is the starting point of a rectangle (pixel), and val is the (some) color function associated with it. How can I do this with Mathematica?

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]

xy = RandomSample[Tuples[Range[0, 10], 2], 10];

z = RandomReal[1, 10];

xyz = Join[xy, List /@ z, 2]
```

> ```
> {{9, 5, 0.941699}, {7, 3, 0.294264}, {1, 3, 0.188274}, {0, 0, 0.761529},
>  {6, 1, 0.169824}, {0, 3, 0.455359}, {5, 10, 0.75425}, {9, 1, 0.268291},
>  {2, 1, 0.147377}, {8, 9, 0.480659}}
> ```

#### Graphics

```
graphics = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Hue @ #3, Rectangle[{#, #2}]} & @@@ xyz, 
 Frame -> True];

legend = SwatchLegend[Hue /@ xyz[[All, -1]], Defer /@ xyz];

Legended[graphics, legend]
```

[image]

#### BubbleChart

```
BubbleChart[xyz, ChartStyle -> (Hue /@ xyz[[All, -1]]), 
 ChartElementFunction -> (Rectangle[Mean /@ #] &), 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {0, 11}}, 
 ChartLegends -> {Defer /@ xyz}]
```

[image]

#### DensityHistogram

```
DensityHistogram[WeightedData[xyz[[All, ;; 2]], xyz[[All, -1]]], {1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Gray], 
 ChartElementFunction -> (Rectangle[Mean /@ #] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[Hue /@ xyz[[All, -1]], Defer /@ xyz]]
```

[image]

#### ListPlot

```
Legended[ReplaceAll[Point -> (Rectangle@*First)]@
  ListPlot[List /@ xyz[[All, ;; 2]], 
   PlotStyle -> Hue /@ xyz[[All, -1]], BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Gray], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 11}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> .2], legend]
```

[image]

#### ArrayPlot

```
ArrayPlot[SparseArray[1 + {#2, #} -> Hue @ #3 & @@@ xyz], 
 DataReversed -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> Table[{# + 1/2, #} & /@ Range[0, 10], 4], 
 PlotLegends -> legend]
```

[image]

#### Update

To have  *"the plot legend to look something like the likes of DensityPlot/ArrayPlot"*, replace `legend` above with `barlegend1` or `barlegend2`, where

```
barlegend1 = BarLegend[{Hue, MinMax@xyz[[All, -1]]}];

barlegend2 = BarLegend[{Hue, MinMax@xyz[[All, -1]]}, xyz[[All, -1]]];

Row[{barlegend1, barlegend2}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Replace `Hue` with  `ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"]` to use the default color scheme for `DensityPlot`:

```
barlegend1 = BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", MinMax@xyz[[All, -1]]}];
barlegend2 = BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", MinMax@xyz[[All, -1]]}, 
   xyz[[All, -1]]];

Row[{barlegend1, barlegend2}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
Legended[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[1], 
   ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"] @ #3, Rectangle[{#, #2}]} & @@@ xyz, 
   Frame -> True], 
  barlegend2]
```

[image]

```
BubbleChart[xyz, 
 ChartStyle -> (ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"] /@ xyz[[All, -1]]), 
 ChartElementFunction -> (Rectangle[Mean /@ #] &), 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {0, 11}}, ChartLegends -> barlegend2]
```

[image]

For `DensityHistogram`, just remove the option `ColorFunction -> Hue`:

```
DensityHistogram[WeightedData[xyz[[All, ;; 2]], xyz[[All, -1]]], {1}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> (Rectangle[Mean /@ #] &), 
 ChartLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, xyz[[All, -1]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, but I need the axes and the plot legends as well!

Comment: @sbp, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thanks. Cant we have the plot legend to look something like the likes of DensityPlot/ArrayPlot...?